# yii2 - use pjax with a gridview inside a modal window

Tags: gridview, yii2, modal-dialog, pjax

I'm trying to use a gridView on a modal dialog, but when I search something in it (filtering), all page refresh and obviously the modal closes.
what I need to make it works properly?.

my code:

view

```
use yii\widgets\Pjax;

<?php
    Modal::begin([
        'id' => 'modal',
        'header' => '<h2>Students</h2>',
        'toggleButton' => ['label' => 'Show Students'],
    ]);
    Pjax::begin();
    echo GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'columns' => [
                'student_code',
                'name',
                'grade',
            ],
         ]);
    Pjax::end();
    Modal::end();
?>
```

controller

```
public function actionDetail($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        $searchModel = new DatosBasicosSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);       

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('detail', [
                'model' => $model,
                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

I have searched on the documentation, tutorials from oficial page and I have find a lot of posts related, but i can't solve the problem.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by the configuration on the begin() method of Pjax, the right way is:

View code:

```
use yii\widgets\Pjax;

<?php
    Modal::begin([
        'id' => 'modal',
        'header' => '<h2>Students</h2>',
        'toggleButton' => ['label' => 'Show Students'],
    ]);

    Pjax::begin([
        'id'=>'pjax-students-gridview',
        'timeout' => false,
        'enablePushState' => false,
    ]);

    echo GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'columns' => [
                'student_code',
                'name',
                'grade',
            ],
         ]);

    Pjax::end();

    Modal::end();
?>
```

The controller code is the same, there is no problem.

Thanks to ***vityapro*** to take me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Try add pjax configuration to `GridView`

```
'pjax' => true,
'pjaxSettings'=>[
    'options'=>[
        'enablePushState'=>false,
    ],
],
```

And create a separate action for your GridView rendering and triggering the filter ... and [configure filterUrl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html#$filterUrl-detail).

Comment: adding this configuration to GridView I get next error: "Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException Setting unknown property: yii\grid\GridView::pjax"